# Program to scan to code files for diffrences?

Tags: plugins, maintainability

Is there any program that will scan two code files, compare, and show you what is different between them. I need such a system as I am building a website using plugins that are regularly updated, however I need to edit the plugins to provide some of the functionality my client wishes to have. I want this to just reduce the amount of time it takes to make the changes to the files in the plugin before it is uploaded to the server and updated.

Comment: you mean something like diff command on unix, or [beyond compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) or [winmerge](http://winmerge.org/)?

Comment: compare between version numbers, that will save up so much trouble, but has great responsibility on developers on updating the numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any diff tool can do this - the unix "diff" is a command-line example, a GUI option for windows is [Sourcegear's DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/). Many text editors also have a diff option built in. Just google for "diff tool" and you'll have many to choose from.